# How does one report bad actors who copy Stack Overflow content and publish it without attribution in commercial books for sale?

Tags: discussion, legal, attribution

I reported some unethical bad actors in India who copied Stack Overflow Python code content and published it without attribution in commercial books for sale.  I received 2 downvotes within 30 minutes.

What is the right way to report bad actors without losing points?

The original Python code in the question by @Seong here was copied verbatim and published in a very poorly written book called "52 Amazing Python Projects for Developers". This book is being sold by the author(s) in India at https://www.edcredibly.com/ I said the book is poorly written because the data files were missing, along with an explanation. I discovered the unethical copying when I came to Stack Overflow to debug the missing data.

The authors in India at https://www.edcredibly.com/ did not provide attribution to @Seong for posting his source code. This is unethical.

This is not the only code example lifted verbatim by the book.

Is copying this content a violation of copyright?

Comment: *"I received 2 downvotes within 30 minutes."*, I'm not sure how you receive downvotes on a copyright lawsuit...

Comment: It is almost certainly a copyright violation. It's not a programming question so it clearly doesn't belong on stack overflow. Realistically, although I think it's helpful to report copyright violations when you find them, it's likely that nothing will be done about it except perhaps to count them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/contact

Comment: It’s unclear the correlation to your reports and downvotes you received. How exactly did you report these bad actors? Why do your believe the downvotes have anything to do with reporting the bad actors instead of say reporting the actions on SO as a out of scope question?

Comment: @SecurityHound Likely on Stack Overflow. This question was migrated, so it seems like they're unaware on Meta, flags, or e-mail.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship - Author has been a SO member for 9 years.

Comment: @SecurityHound It's also their first question on Meta, one which was migrated from main. "Is copying this content a violation of copyright?" Yes. "This is unethical." It is also illegal.

Comment: Copyright law is complex and varies from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. In general, only the copyright holder or their agent can do anything about non-criminal violations of copyright. In many/most jurisdictions, Stack Overflow *can't* actually do anything from a legal standpoint about inappropriately copied user content, because they don't have standing (i.e. they are not the copyright holder or the copyright holder's agent). In other words, the authors of the individual posts would need to take legal action of whatever sort is appropriate for the jurisdiction in which the violations occurs.

Comment: @Makyen So the appropriate action is to notify the copyright holders in comments under their posts?

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship For a low number of users that might be reasonable. It quickly becomes noisy/unreasonable if it's more than just a few users. A probably better alternative would be to invite the user(s) to a chat room

Comment: Related (also allegedly about the license): *[Is SE \[going to be\] selling our content for AI model training? And what exactly does "reinvest back into our communities" mean](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388551/is-se-going-to-be-selling-our-content-for-ai-model-training-and-what-exactly/388552#comment1295589_388552)?*

Comment: IMO there is no appropriate action and there is no inappropriate action. What someone puts in a book for easy profit schemes or what the company has legal issues with is not really our concern. If you want to help them out and report things you see, go ahead. There is a contact link for a reason. But me choosing not to do it because I don't work for Stack Overflow Inc. should be just fine too. Its just a terrible book in a sea of terrible books to me. I once bought a book about Java Swing a long time ago. It was essentially a printout of the online tutorial. I was the stupid one for buying it.

Answer (score 15):

> the authors <...> did not provide attribution

Yes, this is in direct violation of the [CC-BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)'s attribution requirement (doesn't matter if it is unethical or not, it is, plain and simple, a violation of the license).

> in commercial books for sale

Unfortunately, this part is irrelevant for the situation as the license doesn't in any way restrict commercial use.

> Is copying this content a violation of copyright?

Yes, failure to conform with any of the conditions of the license constitutes a copyright violation (insofar it is a violation of the terms of the license grant which has a consequence of revocation of the license unless the issue is fixed in a timely manner [30 days since the violation is discovered]).

> What is the right way to report bad actors <...>?

You may try contacting the company, but it is likely that [you are on your own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343405) in such a case (the linked answer states the official position of Stack Exchange on reports of license violations by scraper websites only, though). The best course of action here for you or affected users, should you or they wish to pursue this further, is to **consult a lawyer** as we, the community, are in no position to give legal advice.

One thing we can definitely advise on is that posting on the *main site* is not the right way of reporting copyright violations. Apart from the usual note that you should not assume who and for what reason downvoted your contribution (as not only those are just guesses, in practice such assumptions rarely [if ever] turn out to be correct). In this case, however, it is pretty obvious where the votes came from: see the first sentence of the paragraph.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in CC but this observation *the data files were missing, along with an explanation.* (assuming this means content was only partially copied) isn't against the license, right? You can re-use/publish only parts of a question or answer as long as you adhere to the attribution requirement.

Comment: @rene I presume you are talking about the content in the book? IIRC, yes, as long as it is attributed anyone is free to do anything with the content fully or partially without violating the terms of the license - or have I misunderstood what are you saying?

Comment: Yeah, that covers it. Thanks.